# Contradictory set exercise

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

(1) How can $\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ if n=1,2,...?

(2) How can $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup A_n$ given the fact $0<\frac{1}{x^2+1}\leqslant1$?

Comment: If $n=1$, then $\dfrac {1} {n+1} = \dfrac 1 2$ and $\dfrac 1 n = 1$. Thus $A_1 = \{ x \mid \dfrac 1 2 < \ldots \le 1 \}$.

Comment: And so on : $A_2 = \{ x \mid \dfrac 1 3 < \ldots \le \dfrac 1 2 \}$.

Comment: $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$, because $\dfrac 1 2$ is not in $A_1$.

Comment: Consider $\{ x \mid 0 < \dfrac 1 x \le 1 \}$. This does not mean $(0,1]$ but $\mathbb  R^+$ because for an enormous value of $x$, $\dfrac 1 x$ will be very small, i.e. near to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $x$ can be any real number, so for example, if $x=7.1$, then $\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{7.1^2+1}=\frac{1}{51.41}\approx 0.01945$, which satisifes $\frac{1}{52} < \frac{1}{7.1^2+1}\leq \frac{1}{51}$.

(2) To show $\cup_n A_n=\mathbb{R}$, you need to show that every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is in some $A_n$. That is, we need to find $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{x^2+1} \leq \frac{1}{n}$, i.e., $n \leq x^2+1 <n+1$. Now it should be clear how to find such an $n$. The answer you provided justifies it slightly differently. It says for any real number $x$, we know $0 < \frac{1}{x^2+1} \leq 1$. Choose the smallest fraction $\frac{1}{n}$ which is bigger than or equal to $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$. Then $\frac{1}{n+1}$ is smaller, so it must be less than $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$. So we conclude $\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{x^2+1} \leq \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. For any positive integer $n$, by solving the inequalities $n \leq x^2+1 <n+1$ we find that $$A_n=(-\sqrt{n},-\sqrt{n-1}]\cup[\sqrt{n-1},\sqrt{n}).$$